# Alternative to Vector of Plotmath Expressions

Tags: r, r-grid, plotmath

I'm trying to label an axis at every 3rd tick with a 10^n value, formatted as a superscript.  I'm using `grid` graphics.  I'm doing something bassackwards.  Here's a MWE (or I see there is some movement to call it a reprex):

```
library("grid")
grid.newpage()
axisVP <- viewport(width = unit(6, "inches"), height = unit(0.01, "inches"))
pushViewport(axisVP)
labs <- c(1, "", "", expression(10^{-3}), "", "", expression(10^{-6}), "", "",
   expression(10^{-9}), "", "", expression(10^{-12}))
grid.xaxis(at = seq(0, 1, length.out = 15)[-c(1,15)], label = labs)
```

However, this only labels the first tick with 1.  Looking at `str(labs)` it is an expression with length 13 as expected. And expressions are accepted by `grid.xaxis`.  So I'm not quite sure why only the first value is being displayed.  I've explored related questions on SO but most seem to deal with a single expression as an axis label or title, not a series of expressions. And most questions dealing with axis labels seek to label every tick using a specialized function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
axisVP <- viewport(width = unit(6, "inches"), height = unit(0.01, "inches"))
pushViewport(axisVP)

## First plot an axis with all ticks and no labels
ticks_at <- seq(1/15, 14/15, length.out=13)
grid.xaxis(at = ticks_at, label=FALSE)

## Then add labels where you want them
labs <- parse(text=c("1", "10^{-3}", "10^{-6}", "10^{-9}", "10^{-12}"))
## Alternatively, use this, though in practice it's more cumbersome
# labs <- c(expression(1), expression(10^{-3}), expression(10^{-6}), 
#           expression(10^{-9}), expression(10^{-12}))
labs_at <- seq(1/15, 14/15, length.out=5)
grid.xaxis(at = labs_at, label = labs)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  There's some magic in there with `parse` and `text` which I shall have to study.  I also appreciate your alternate (and conceptually superior) way of conveying the sequences.  And leaner code generally.

Comment: You're welcome! For learning about what `parse()` is doing in this context, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Internal-representation) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Expression-objects) in the R language definition. (As it turns out, this is one of the very few situations in which you should probably ever be using `parse()` to construct R language objects. For better alternatives, see the section [Computing on the Language](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language).)

Comment: (It might be worth noting that, if you want some of your expressions to print nothing, you'll need to set them to something like `phantom(.)`.)

Comment: I did try `phantom()` in my overly complex original version of `labs`, but it performed the the same as empty quotes.  Thanks for the additional references.